# Answer redirect IP to specific port

Tags: centos, iptables, nat

I want make a system that has a few subdomains. I set each subdomain to IP address using DNS.

*I used random IP addresses for the question*

165.93.198.34 x.mydomain.com (Which is actually 165.93.198.220:8080)

165.93.198.38 z.mydomain.com (Which is actually 165.93.198.220:81)

165.93.198.44 c.mydomain.com (Which is actually 165.93.198.220:443)

165.93.198.220 mydomain.com

Using iptables, when a request comes to IP address `165.93.198.34` I want it to be answered from `165.93.198.220:8080`.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 165.93.198.34  --jump DNAT --to-destination 165.93.198.220:8080
```

But I couldn't make the prerouting work.

```
[root@static ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:down
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:81
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination



[root@static ~]# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             165.93.198.34-iprovider.com to:165.93.198.220:8080

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My answer might not work, I am not sure. How is your system setup? Are you using virtual interfaces for your 3 IPs .34, .38 and .44? And your Destination .220 is it another system in the network?

Comment: @rda It worked well, thank you so much. net.ipv4.ip_forward was the key.

Comment: You're welcome. Please answer my question from above, I am just interested in how you did this exactly.

Comment: @rda nano /etc/sysctl.conf, changing net.ipv4.ip_forward to 1

Comment: Sorry, I meant the network part with the IPs and so on.

Comment: Same server has 4 ip addresses. I just wanted to answer from different ip for each subdomain I have. Sorry for late response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your target IP (165.93.198.220) is another system in the network**

add an `ACCEPT` rule in the `FORWARD` chain like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 165.93.198.220 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

also check if ip forward is enabled:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

if it is not set to `1`, enable it on the fly with:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

or

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

to make it persistent for reboots edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**If your target IP (165.93.198.220) is on the local machine**

add an `ACCEPT` rule in the `INPUT` chain like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```